# Panels not working with page manager?

Tags: 8, panels

I'm testing page_manager on a fresh install of Drupal 8 (V 8.1.8).

I installed :

- [Layout Plugin](https://www.drupal.org/project/layout_plugin) 8.x-1.0-alpha22
- [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) 8.x-3.0-beta4
- [Page Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager) 8.x-1.0-alpha24 (with page_manager_ui)

When I try to create a Panel variant in a custom page, I've got no option to insert a block...

My UI appears like that :

[image: no option to insert content]

Where can I add content in this page ?

Comment: Yes, they are not. try the latest dev of panels and check the issue queue if that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Panels and [Page Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager) in Drupal 8 are under heavy development, so probably it's a temporal problem.

In Drupal 7 Page Manager is a submodule of [CTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools), but in Drupal 8 is a standalone module. The reason for this is Page Manager tasks (configuring UI) are very important but Panels wants to remain independent from the UI. This makes sense, as each module focus on its duty (Panels on doing its magic, Page Manager in configuring Panels through the UI).

To be more accurated Panels in Drupal 8 can be *implemented*. Currently, Page Manager and [Panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer) implement panels.

So now they are not working together, but eventually they should, that's the target.

Comment: Hi Sanzante,
I imagined that if I can select panel as variant type in the dropdown menu they where suposed to work together.
But Drupal 8, new modules, new concept, new philosophy (I'm joking, I love Drupal ;-)

PS : page_manager was not a sub module of Panels but ctools

Comment: You are right, it's in CTools.